# How to use cell variables in filter function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Being pretty new to google sheets I hope to find a way to use a cell as a variable without having to code custom functions for it.

For example how do I use this function:

[image]

so that I can declare a cell as a variable and use it in the function?

Attempts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=filter(indirect(E8); not(isblank(indirect(E9))))
```

or

```
=filter(indirect(E8); len(indirect(E9)))
```

[image: Example]